# Spring Boot Mock MVC applying filter to wrong url pattern

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockmvc

I'm adding an admin filter to a specific URL like this

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<AdminFilter> adminFilterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<AdminFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        AdminFilter adminFilter = new AdminFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(adminFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/user/activate");
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/user/deactivate");
        registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

While I'm testing it with postman or in browser, the filter is applied correctly, only applied to those URL pattern.

But, when I write test for it, somehow the filter is applied to another URL too.

```
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api/issue/").header("Authorization", defaultToken)
            ).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json("{}"));
```

This code return an error with code "403", on the log it says because the user is not an admin, which means the admin filter applied to "/api/issue/" URL on the mock mvc request.

I'm using `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` with `@Autowired` to instantiate the mockMVC.

anyone know why it's happening?

---

Full code of the admin filter:

```
@Component
public class AdminFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (userService == null){
            ServletContext servletContext = servletRequest.getServletContext();
            WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
            userService = webApplicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);
        }

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        UUID userId = UUID.fromString((String)httpRequest.getAttribute("userId"));
        User user = userService.fetchUserById(userId);
        if (!user.getIsAdmin()) {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), "User is not an admin");
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Full code of the test file:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public class RepositoryIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryRepository repositoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private String defaultToken;
    private String otherToken;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        User defaultUser = userRepository.save(new User("username", "email@mail.com", "password"));
        System.out.println(defaultUser);
        User otherUser = userRepository.save(new User("other", "other@mail.com", "password"));
        defaultToken = "Bearer " + generateJWTToken(defaultUser);
        otherToken = "Bearer " + generateJWTToken(otherUser);
    }

    private String generateJWTToken(User user) {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return Jwts.builder().signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, Constants.API_SECRET_KEY)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(timestamp))
            .setExpiration(new Date(timestamp + Constants.TOKEN_VALIDITY))
            .claim("userId", user.getId())
            .compact();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnAllRepositoriesAvailableToUser() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api/issue/").header("Authorization", defaultToken)
            ).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json("{}"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this is the filter but rather you have a security configuration and haven't setup the testing properly so it doesn't authenticate.

Comment: Well the error message say the exact same thing as what I write on the filter, it says `User is not an admin` and when I change the error message on the filter, it changes too on the tests response.

Comment: Now that is something you didn't mention. Could you add your test and a bit more configuration? As there currently isn't enough information. Also what does the filter actually do?

Comment: I've edited the questions to include the full code of the filter and the tests. Basically the filter only check for attribute isAdmin on the user.

Comment: Remove `@Component` your filter is registered twice. Once with and once without a filterregistration. When there is no filter registration it will be added automatically by Spring bOot and will be registered with `/*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AdminFilter` is being registered twice. Once through the `FilterRegistrationBean` and once due to the fact that it is an `@Component` and thus detected by component scanning.

To fix do one of 2 things

1. Remove `@Component`
2. Re-use the automatically created instance for the `FilterRegistrationBean`.

Removing `@Component` is easy enough, just remove it from the class.

For option 2 you can inject the automatically configured filter into the `FilterRegistrationBean` configuration method, instead of creating it yourself.

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<AdminFilter> adminFilterRegistrationBean(AdminFilter adminFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<AdminFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(adminFilter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/user/activate");
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/user/deactivate");
    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

An added advantage of this is that you can use autowiring to set up dependencies instead of doing lookups in the `init` method. I would also suggest using the `OncePerRequestFilter`. This would clean up your filter considerably.

```java
@Component
public class AdminFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    public AdminFilter(UserService userService) {
        this.userService=userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        UUID userId = UUID.fromString((String)httpRequest.getAttribute("userId"));
        User user = userService.fetchUserById(userId);
        if (!user.getIsAdmin()) {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), "User is not an admin");
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```